# Conditional HiddenInputAttribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I need an attribute in ASP .NET MVC view model, which check the specified condition (based on another property value) and turn on/off visibility parameter of input control on edit page.

Something like that:

```
public string SomeProperty { get; set; }

[ConditionalHidden("SomeProperty", "PropertyValueToMakeConditionTrue")]
public string DependentProperty { get; set; }
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you need it after page is loaded then you need javascript code.

Else you can use in view

```
@if(Model.Property == something)
    {
        html
    }
```

But this is without attribute.

Comment: Unfortunately, edit page is auto-generated and I can't modify it